# Django doesn't serve static files properly

Tags: python, django

I'm making a todo app using Django and Vue js. I've added the path to serve staticfiles with: `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)`
the server returns a 200 OK response, with the file in it. But the file isn't updated, according to the modifies i do. How can this happen?

Comment: Please indicate how you verified that you're using the same virtual environment that you installed pygame in.

Comment: Yes, I modified an old question, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to make another :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just an environment problem, as you installed the `pygame` in the global python interpreter environment while not installed it in the virtual environment which you selected in the VSCode.

Check it:

1. `where python` in the cmd, `get-command python` in the PowerShell. to check which python you are using.

2.`pip show pygame` to check the location of the `pygame` package.

Comment: Ok I've noticed that pygame is installed both in the global python both in the venv, and from code I was using the global python as @Random Davis supposed.

Comment: @Nicolò Teseo Sorry, could you find the 'pygame' under the 'site-packages' in your virtual environment? Because the exception message hint it using the virtual environment 'venv', but it could not find 'pygame' package.